# Kube API extension server client-cert-based authorization does not work with kubeconfig file client-certificate-data

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-rbac

Currently on k8s 1.24.13

I have client cert auth enabled and functioning normally (almost) from my extension api-server using the `client-ca-file` option with clients presenting certs in which the Common Name (CN) maps to a User subject in RBAC rules. This works great for my use case with HTTPS traffic from containers.

More info on this here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs

However, when I present a client to the server via a kubeconfig file which includes `certificate-authority-data`, `client-certificate-data`, and `client-key-data` (all base64 encoded) the responses from my extension api-server indicate that instead of reading the CN from the presented client cert data in the kubeconfig, it is ignoring this and attempting to fallback to a default service account which ofcourse does not have the proper permissions. I can confirm this is happening from both a container that uses a kubeconfig method to connect, and when I attempt to use a kubeconfig directly from outside the cluster network.

Example error response (despite providing a proper cert in kubeconfig):

```
 User "system:serviceaccount:ops:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Context: `ops` is the namespace where this combo kube-api-server + kube-controller-manager pod is running.

I've verified the cert data is correct, verified the RBAC rules are setup for the cert CN I am expecting to be presented, but I don't know where else to look. It doesn't make sense that specifically using kubeconfig method to connect results in the cert data being effectively ignored.

Comment: I've had to resort to static token auth with kubeconfig/kubectl until I can figure this out but I would highly prefer to have only 1 auth method enabled on the extension server.

Comment: Can you please share your ClusterRole and ClusterRolebinding yaml files. Also you have to allow the serviceaccount that you are using to list some resources from kubernetes otherwise it will fail. It is failing because the serviceaccount doesnt have enough permissions to be able to do some actions. You can define new permissions or create anoñther serviceAccount to avoid editing the default one that comes from Kubernetes.

Comment: Did you have time to check my comment? Have you given the permisions to serviceaccount? Does it help to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.